# Calling a function from a class

Tags: apache-flex

```
package asas
{           
  public class main extends EventDispatcher
  {
    private static  var instance:main =new main;

    // This method returns the instance of the class.
    public static function get instance() : main {
      if(_instance == null){
        _instance = new main();            
      }
      return _instance;
    }

    public function doCheck():void {
    }
```

I have this class and a MXML file... how will i call the function doCheck in button. When i call like this, it throws me an error.

```
<mx:Button
   styleName="LoginButton"
   id="loginButton" 
   click="main.instance.doCheck();" 
   x="160" 
   y="261"
 />
```

Comment: In the future please include the error you get; it will help people to diagnose your problem faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your private instance variable is named `instance`, but your trying to assign to a variable called `_instance` in the getter.

Change this:

```
private static var instance:main =new main;
```

to this:

```
private static var _instance:main;
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeff L is right on implementation.  The _instance property should always be uninitialized or set to null.  That said, that is not the issue here.

I have had poor results when trying to get MXML to read methods off of properties of other objects in that notation.  I recommend replacing this:

```
<mx:Button
   styleName="LoginButton"
   id="loginButton" 
   click="main.instance.doCheck();" 
   x="160" 
   y="261"
/>
```

with one that uses brackets:

```
<mx:Button
   styleName="LoginButton"
   id="loginButton" 
   click="{ main.instance.doCheck(); }"
   x="160" 
   y="261"
/>
```

That generally will give me more reliable behavior, and I think that will help here too.

Answer (score 0):

This line of the code doesn't make sense, because in your code you use undeclared variable.

```
private static  var instance:main =new main;
```

use should change it to:

```
private static var _instance:main;
```